# Returning multiples of a decimal number in Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-03'],
'Time':['09:47:07.136','09:57:13.757','09:58:26.841','09:28:31.161','09:28:43.562'], 
'Price': [1.80,1.855,1.598,30.010,25.985]})
```

I would like to filter out those Price value that is not a multiple of a certain number (tick size), meaning, for Price ranges between $0.10 and $2.00, the multiple (tick size) is $0.005. For Price more than or equal to $2.00, the multiple (tick size) is $0.01.

Therefore, the ideal df after filtering will be:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['BBB','BBB','CCC'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-03'],
'Time':['09:47:07.136','09:57:13.757','09:28:31.161'], 
'Price': [1.80,1.855,30.010]})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[(df["Price"] >= 0.1) & (df["Price"] <= 2) & (df["Price"]/0.005%1 == 0)]
```

This is for the first condition, you can complete on your own the second condition by the same way.
To filter on dataframe: `df[condition1 & condition2]` (and-ish relation). Condition 1 is just the ranges and it's pretty straight-forward. The second condition for the price tick: like in basic questions when learns coding, you first divide it by tick and see if it's an integer (by take modulus 1 and see if it's zero). Just like if you want to see if 4.2 is a multiplication of 2: you dived by tick and check there is a reminder.

P.S - next time, give example of what you already tried or what you get stuck on. Don't just ask for a solution

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
newdf = df.loc[(df["Price"].between(0.1,2)) & (df["Price"]/0.005%1 == 0)]
```